# Azure Datafactory: How to implement nested sql query in transformation data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I have two streams **customer** and **customercontact**. I am new to azure data factory. I just want to know which activity in data flow transformation will achieve the below sql query result.

(SELECT *
FROM customercontact
WHERE customerid IN
(SELECT customerid
FROM customer)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1)

I can utilize Exist transformation for inner query but I am need some help on how I can fetch the first row after sorting customer contact data.So , basically I am looking for a way to add limit/Top/Offset clause in dataflow.

Comment: The query you have will only return the most recent customer's contact.., what you intend to do with the returned contact record (s)?

Comment: Yes , it will return most recent customer contact. I have join this other table. I need data flow transformation for above mentioned query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve transformation for a given query in data flow with different transformation.

For sorting you can use Sort transformation. Here you can select Order Ascending or descending.

[image]

For top few records you can use Rank transformation.

[image]

For “IN” clause you can use Exists transformation.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-rank

[image]

Here is my sample data in SQL as Source

[image]

I have used Rank transformation.

[image]

After rank transformation one more column i.e. RankColumn got added.

[image]

Now to select only top 1 record I have used Filter Row Modifier. I used `equals(RankColumn,1)` expression to select Top 1 record.

[image]

[image]

Now finally use Sink activity and run pipeline.